# Can't create Type Library File with Visual Studio 2010 generated DLL, but can with command-line compiled

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, com, compilation

I have a TestClass.cs file that contains an interface, and a class, much like this:

```
namespace CPierce.CSharpBridge
{
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Guid("3D08DF02-EFBA-4A65-AD84-B08ADEADBEEF")]
    public interface ICSide
    {
        // interface definition omitted...
    }
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Guid("CBC04D81-398B-4B03-A3D1-C6D5DEADBEEF")]
    public partial class CSide : ICSide
    {
        // class definition omitted...
    }
}
```

When I compile this at the command line, and run regasm on it:

```
csc /debug /t:library TestClass.cs 
regasm TestClass.dll /tlb:TestClass.tlb
```

I get a nice, big .tlb file suitable for including in a C++ project elsewhere....

```
 10/27/2011  01:50 PM             3,616 TestClass.tlb
```

When I put TestClass.cs into a "Class Project" in Visual Studio, compile it, run regasm, the resulting .tlb is pathetic and nearly useless -- it has no interface, no method signatures, etc...

```
[Compiled TestClass.cs as part of Project "ClassProject" in Visual Studio]
regasm ClassProject.dll /tlb:ClassProject.dll

10/27/2011  01:58 PM             1,132 ClassProject.tlb
```

**This is the same C# code in both cases**, one being compiled with Visual Studio one at the command line, giving me completely different results.

What gives?

--

Update:  Hans suggests that the `[ComVisible(true)]` attribute missing is causing the problem.  Tried it, and it worked.  But that still doesn't answer the question, *why*?  Why do I get different results based on which compile method I use?

Comment: You forgot the [ComVisible(true)] attribute.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exsposing indexer like properties to COM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452391/exsposing-indexer-like-properties-to-com)

Comment: Right...but why does that only affect the Visual Studio compilation and not the command-line version?

Comment: "Make assembly COM-Visible" option in the IDE, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a new Class Library in Visual Studio, the default AssemblyInfo.cs file includes the line:

```
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]
```

The command-line command you're using is only compiling your TestClass.cs file, so you get the default setting for ComVisible (which, judging from the available evidence, is probably `true`). When you compile from the IDE, you include AssemblyInfo.cs as well, so its explicit setting overrides the compiler's default.

Answer (score 0):

Also check if your class has functions of accessor type **public**.

In our case, the project was working fine when it was being used from within the solution but when we extracted the logic to create a **DLL**, it stopped creating the **TLB** file with no indication on why...

So if you have a class like so,

```
public class tlbuser{    
    private void functionTLB(){
        //function code
    }
    // rest of the class code
}
```

Ensure it is changed to:

```
public class tlbuser{    
    public void functionTLB(){
        //function code
    }
    // rest of the class code
}
```