# vb.net equivalent of vb6 function attributes

Tags: vb.net, vb6, attributes, vb6-migration

I have the follow class in `vb6`:

```
Public Function NewEnum()
    Attribute NewEnum.VB_UserMemId = -4
    Attribute NewEnum.VB_MemberFlags = "40"

    NewEnum = mcolFields.[_NewEnum]

End Function
```

What would the equivalent attributes be in `vb.net?` I know that you have to put attributes in `<>`and I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24193950/vb-net-equivalent-of-vb6-attribute-item-vb-usermemid-0) SO post, however it didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GetEnumerator() is the exact equivalent.  It gets exposed as NewEnum in `<ComVisible(True)>` code.  Simply implement the System.Collections.IEnumerable interface, the non-generic one.

Answer (score 1):

Some info about this is here: https://christopherjmcclellan.wordpress.com/2015/04/21/vb-attributes-what-are-they-and-why-should-we-use-them/

> There is one more special value for VB_UserMemId and that value is -4.
>   Negative 4 always indicates that the function being marked should
>   return a [_NewEnum] enumerator.

I would say that in this case you can ignore them. So your equivalent should be something like this:

```
Public Function NewEnum() As mcolFields
    Return New mcolFields
End Function
```