# Indexer in C# Library for VBA throws an error when a value is assigned

Tags: c#, vba, office-interop

I have written a C# library(Kvp) for VBA which is essentially a wrapper for a C# dictionary. All of the methods I have implemented work fine from VBA. However the indexer is throwing errors when I assign to an item in the Dictionary (the same problem occurs if I change from a dictionary to a HashTable).

In VBA

```vb
myObject.Item(Index) = a_value
```

throws an error saying that an object is required.

If I cast `myObject` to Object then the indexer works as expected.

```vb
Dim myObj as Object
Set myObj = myObject
myObj.Item(Index) = a_value
```

To confirm that the Indexer was the problem I added `GetItem` and `SetItem` methods to the C# library and found that these worked as expected.

In the Interface

```cs
dynamic this[dynamic Key] { get; set; }
dynamic GetItem(dynamic myIndex);    
void SetItem(dynamic myIndex, dynamic myValue);
```

In the Implementation

```cs
private Dictionary<dynamic, dynamic> MyKvp = new Dictionary<dynamic, dynamic>();

public dynamic this[dynamic Key]
{    
    get
    {
        return MyKvp[Key];
    }
    set
    {
        MyKvp[Key] = value;
    }

public dynamic GetItem(dynamic myIndex)
    {
        return MyKvp[myIndex];
    }
}

public void SetItem(dynamic myIndex, dynamic myValue)
{
    MyKvp[myIndex] = myValue;
}
```

I can continue with the cast to Object workaround but to be honest it is a bit of a pain as it means that everywhere I change from Scripting.Dictionary to myObject I have to update the associated code. Of course I could revert to implementing myObject in VBA but I'm trying to learn c# and this library is my first project in the learning curve.  Please note that I am not a professional programmer.

An of course the question is. How do I revise the C# library such that the Indexer works as expected in VBA?

Amended 13 Dec

Please note that I have a long list of unit tests using the Rubberduck add in.  All tests pass except the Indexer assignment.  The Indexer assignment test works if I VBA cast to an object as explained above.

Amedenment 2 13 Dec Updated as Amendment 4

In respone to @Gser'g question I've corrected the image for the Kvp Object and also added an image of the IKvp interface .

In the Interface

```
[Guid("6DC1808F-81BA-4DE0-9F7C-42EA11621B7E")]
[ComVisible(true)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface IKvp
```

In the Implementation

```
[Guid("434C844C-9FA2-4EC6-AB75-45D3013D75BE")]
[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
public class Kvp : IKvp, IEnumerable
```

[image: Object Browser for Kvp from VBA]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Amendment 3 A confession

I have asked the same question in Code Review but its not getting much interest.  The whole code for the Kvp object is included at

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/233671/c-dictionary-wrapper-for-vba

Comment: Did you try following : MyKvp[Key] = (object)value;

Comment: Does the VBA code have an OPTION BASE 1 ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-base-statement

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for the suggestion.  Using the (object)  cast in the Indexer does not resolve the issue.

Comment: @Tony  All the relevant methods for populating a 'myObject' start with a Key of 0 if the Key is  integer (that means from VBA an Integer, Long or LongLong).

Comment: Using the [Guid] attribute is quite risky.  You'll have no protection against the VBA code using a stale type library or loading an old copy of the DLL.  A generic problem called "DLL Hell".  Which can cause all kind of mishaps when it calls the completely wrong method or property setter.  Casting to Object is a workaround for that, it forces the VBA runtime to lookup the property at runtime.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the observation.  I commented out the Guid ID lines and the Library still compiles so that another step up the learning curve.

Comment: I believe it is answered in https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/66be03a9-27e0-4ca8-b289-6c739543f302/c-class-indexer-access-from-vb6-via-com-interop?forum=clr.

Comment: Another view on the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6453646/11683

Comment: @GSerg Thanks for the links.  The second is from before C# implemented indexers but does recommend writing the Interface in VB.NET as this has no problem with indexed properties. But I don't think I'm upto doing the necessary jiggery pokery.  I'm happy to have a bash as reimplementing the c# library in VB.NET  but it would still be nice to get an interanl C# solution.

Comment: No, it is not from before C# implemented indexers. It uses VB to create a parametrized property instead of an indexer. C# still does not have that.

Comment: @GSerg Sorry, My confusion.  I've now implemented the library in VB.NET but I get the same problem.